# need to transform xml payload coming from jms in mule

Tags: xml, jms, mule-studio, dataweave

For my project, I need to publish a XML payload on active MQ using JMS. After that I need to transform in another XML format. My problem is, while transforming I am not able to read that XML. In transform message component, in input side I am not getting that XML as payload instead I am getting POJO class of JMS.
So, how should I read XML payload since I have to transform some attribute from that XML payload.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the content-type or mime-type of the message after the jms queue?

Comment: mime-type after jms queue is text/xml.